# Image processor Grayscale -> Duotone -> Error popup "Sorry, I could not process the following files:"

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an issue with `Image processor` (Photoshop 2024). My action does two things:

1. Grayscale
2. Duotone

When I run Image processor (although inside Photoshop images are `correctly` modified), they are **NOT saved** and I get error popup with message `Sorry, I could not process the following files`. If I do Image processor with `some other actions` (not grayscale and not duotone), everything works ok (images are processed and saved correctly).

I am in the darkness, what could be the issue?

Comment: Hi. What format are you trying to save the results of your action as?  Not all formats support duotone colour mode. As far as I know only PSD, PSB, EPS and PDF do.

Comment: Damn I think there is something wrong with Image processor because even basic batch saving (without using any action) to folder fails. I was doing duotone actions batch with JPG files.

Comment: Batch went OK (grayscale -> duotone (I actually use monotone)) when I save it as .PSD. But how now batch save from .PSD to .JPG ? This throws the same popup error as before.

Comment: I have managed to get OK similar result with Action -> Fill layer.

Comment: Duotone mode won't work with JPEGs. The file format doesn't support that colour mode. You will need to convert to RGB if you want a JPEG.  So in your action do Image > Mode > Greyscale, then make your Duotone, then convert to RGB.

Comment: Thx @BillyKerr, converting to RGB in the end works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments I have used solution with Layer fill action with alpha and desired color. This way Image processor works ok.

EDIT: Also -> Converting to RGB solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have a multi colour logo want to reduce it so we can glass etch it onto glasses etc. Any help please
This is  new project. I have the logo and it is in various shades of pink. CCan this be reduced to a monochrome setup to be able to have etching paste used to transfer the image onto glass.